# How do i add functional search box inside select tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a select dropdown and trying to add search box at the top of available options,
I have found a way using chosen library but I want to implement it with javascript or jquery.

how can I do this?

[image]

```css
.Organization_Desg_filter_select {
    padding: 10px 0px;
    border-width: 0px;
    width: 240px;
}
```

```html
<label class="mt-3 mb-0">Designation Name:</label>
                            <select class="Organization_Desg_filter_select">
                                <option selected="selected" disabled>Select</option>
                                <option value="Public Relationship Officer">Public Relationship Officer</option>
                                <option value="Officer">Officer</option>
                                <option value="Associate">Associate</option>
                                <option value="Executive">Executive</option>
                                <option value="Head of Department">Head of Department</option>
                            </select>
                            <hr class="mt-0" />
```

Comment: So Chosen _is_ jquery lib, why not use it? You need additional input for search and filter results on change. There are plenty of these "combo inputs" libraries

Comment: I am asked to try it without chosen library, I need to write the script

Comment: So you have example of how it should be, write code. Return to SO when you have error and can't google it out

Answer (score 0):

if you have to use Third party jQuery than use Select2 https://select2.org/searching

Answer (score -1):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="name">My best friend name:</label>
<input id="name" name="name" list="name-list" value="Szymon"/>

<datalist id="name-list">
    <option value="Albert">
    <option value="Szymon">
    <option value="Michał">
    <option value="Diana">
    <option value="Marek">
    <option value="Kuba">
</datalist>
```

Comment: At first it needs to display "select" by default and search box as one of options that displays after it is selected

Comment: @HarshaPenugonda set `value="Szymon"` and check